# how to run makeparallel with gnu make?

Tags: gnu-make

Consider this simple Makefile, which pretends to run `xz` with the number of workers derived from available jobs. Let's use [makeparallel](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/tools/makeparallel/) for this:

```
%.xz: %.mp4
    @echo xz $$(makeparallel echo | sed 's/j/T/') $<
```

When I run it:

```
$ make -j4 t1.xz t2.xz
xz -T10 t1.mp4
xz -T10 t2.mp4
$
```

Expected output:

```
$ make -j4 t1.xz t2.xz
xz -T2 t1.mp4
xz -T1 t2.mp4
$
```

(or some other combination that adds up to 3).

As you may have guessed, I would like to start `xz -T<N>`, where N is the number of available-workers-at-the-time in GNU Make. But it always uses 10. How can I run `makeparallel` sub-commands with the expected number of workers?

Debian Bullseye amd64, gnu make 4.3-4, makeparallel 1:8.1.0+r23-5

To re-construct the test case:

1. Create a Makefile like above.
2. `touch t1.mp4 t2.mp4`
3. `make <...>`

Comment: For what I know you can't get number of free workers in GNU Make. Even if you did, the number might increase mid-compression in which case you would like to use them, right? I'd run make with lower priority, e.g. `nice make ...`, in case you're worried about the machine becoming unresponsive. Another solution being use of a lock file to prevent concurrent `xz` invocations.

Comment: I am fine in not using the cores; as long as it's >1 in the general case, I am fine. I am then curious what `makeparallel` is for.

Comment: Never heard of `makeparallel`. What is it? Guessing it's not https://github.com/clarkfitzg/makeParallel

Comment: added a link to the wuestion

Comment: Reading makeparallel.cpp it would seem failing to open or read the jobserver file descriptor, in which case it fall backs to system processor count + 2. No clue as to why. Are you perhaps running this in Cygwin or other not-quite-POSIX environment?

Comment: added OS and versions. The test case is trivial to re-construct, feel free to experiment.